# Restrict File Type Uploads by User on Wordress via functions.php

Tags: php, functions, uploads

We've recently added a formidable form onto our client's site which is allowing uploads of images for a competition. Despite restricting this to JPG/PNGs only, bots are still managing to upload dodgy PDF files every hour or less. I don't want to manually have to delete these each day.

Therefore I'm looking to restrict all users other than admins to be able to only upload images e.g JPG's and PNGs but still allow admins to upload pdfs etc. (Or even better would be to prevent unregistered users from uploading anything other than JPGs and PNGs!)

I've been trying the following functions.php code but it still seems to restrict admins from uploading PDFs:

```
add_filter('upload_mimes','restict_mime'); 
function restict_mime($mimes) { 
if(!current_user_can(‘administrator’)){
    $mimes = array( 
                'jpg|jpeg|jpe' => 'image/jpeg', 
                'png' => 'image/png', 
    ); 
}
    return $mimes;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: why do you expect that the code will work in your forms?

Comment: @MarkKaplun The forms just upload to wordpress' basic uploads folder. It allows me to restrict file types but clearly bots are getting around this restriction and still managing to upload files without actually submitting the form. I know they're coming through the forms as Sucuri is alerting me of this and the uploads are in the formidable folder.

The above mentioned code is unrelated to the forms and purely from a Wordpress upload perspective. Using the main theme functions.php. As the form uses Wordpress upload, implementing the restriction for this should work for Forms too.

Comment: if the files come from the form, than the form code do not handle the mime restrictions correctly, if it is true changing the filters used by core will not help. If you specific code here works for upload on admin side and do not work for the forms, than the form probably don't do any mime chacks